# How to find the file format using Java(suppose .txt files,.java files,.class files,.zip files are in my directory)?

Tags: java

How to find the file format using Java(suppose .txt files, .java files, .class files, .zip files are in my directory)?

I need only .txt files is body provide solution it might be help full.

```
public class a {
    public static void main(String[] ar) {
        File f = new File("D:\\") 
        file[] = f.listFiles();
        if (file.isFile && file is txt) {
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: maybe you implement the funktion isText(file) and show us what happens?

Comment: there is no such method isText is available

Answer (score 2):

Use [File#listFiles(FilenameFilter)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles(java.io.FilenameFilter)) instead of File#listFiles():

```
f.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            private Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\.txt");

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return pattern.matcher(name).matches();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If i did understood you correctly you wanna find the file extensions , here is sample application I made for you using swing worker , you can now scan your entire computer with specific file extensions you defined in program  currently it finds html ,  txt and pdf you can modify that.

[Here is the entire project package](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mua4rd1w5gf4dz0/FileExtensionFinder.zip?dl=0)

[image]

**Create Scan Worker Class Like this below and fix the imports using IDE**

```
    public class ScanWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

    ResultFrame helperv;
    int finalTotal = 0;
    String str3;

    public String status;

    public ScanWorker(ResultFrame x) {

        finalTotal = 0;
        helperv = x;
        helperv.jTarea.setText("");

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

        helperv.jTarea.replaceSelection("Scanning..." + "\n");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        callMainScan();

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {

        for (String str : chunks) {

            helperv.jTarea.append(str);
            helperv.scanlabel.setText(str);

        }

    }

    @Override

    protected void done() {

        helperv.scanlabel.setText("Total Number of Files Matched: " + Integer.toString(finalTotal));

    }

    private void callMainScan() throws IOException {

        String[] myStringArray = new String[3];

        myStringArray[0] = "*.txt";
        myStringArray[1] = "*.html";
        myStringArray[2] = "*.pdf";

        File[] paths;

        paths = File.listRoots();

        try {

            for (File path : paths) {

                String str = path.toString();
                String slash = "\\";

                String s = new StringBuilder(str).append(slash).toString();

                Path startingDir = Paths.get(s);

                for (String stre : myStringArray) {

                    String pattern = stre;

                    Finder finder = new Finder(pattern);
                    Files.walkFileTree(startingDir, finder);
                    finder.done();

                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occured");
        }

    }

    public class Finder
            extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

        private final PathMatcher matcher;
        private int numMatches = 0;

        Finder(String pattern) {
            matcher = FileSystems.getDefault()
                    .getPathMatcher("glob:" + pattern);
        }

        // Compares the glob pattern against
        // the file or directory name.
        void find(Path file) {
            Path name = file.getFileName();
            if (name != null && matcher.matches(name)) {
                numMatches++;
                System.out.println(file);
                str3 = file.toString();

                publish(str3 + "\n");

            }
        }

        // Prints the total number of
        // matches to standard out.
        void done() {
//            System.out.println("Matched: "
//                    + numMatches);
            finalTotal = finalTotal + numMatches;
        }

        // Invoke the pattern matching
        // method on each file.
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
                BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
            find(file);
            return CONTINUE;
        }

        // Invoke the pattern matching
        // method on each directory.
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir,
                BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
            find(dir);
            return CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file,
                IOException exc) {
//            System.err.println(exc);
            return CONTINUE;
        }
    }

}
```

**Scan Button Action**

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            sw = new ScanWorker(ResultFrame.this);

            sw.execute();

        }
    }).start();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
public static String getExtension(File file) {
        String fileName = file.getName();
        int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (i > 0) {
            return fileName.substring(i + 1);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arr) {
        File f = new File("D:\\");
        File files[] = f.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                if ("txt".equals(getExtension(file))) {
                    System.out.println(file.getName()+" is a text file");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `getExtensions` could return `null`, so I would write `"txt".equals(getExtension(file))` instead of `getExtension(file).equals("txt")` to prevent NPE

Comment: @msrd0 It wont be null as I am already checking `if (file.isFile())` and if `file` is a `file` not a `dir` then it wont return `null`.

Comment: Yes it will be `null` if the file has no extension, like it happens sometimes on Linux

Comment: @msrd0 Oops I forgot about that , Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `File.listFiles(FilenameFilter)` for it; like this:

```
File[] files = f.listFiles((File dir, String name) -> name.endsWith(".txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
String directory = "c:";
File file = new File(directory);
if (file.isDirectory()) {
    File[] files = file.listFiles();
    System.out.println(files.length);
    for (File innerFiles : files) {
        String fileName = innerFiles.getName();
        if (fileName.contains(".") && 
                (fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("."), fileName.length())
                         .equalsIgnoreCase(".txt"))
                System.out.println(fileName);
    }
}
```